# What's the best way to work with a sharepoint site?

Tags: sharepoint, wysiwyg

I'm a developer who's never used MS SharePoint to manage web sites. The company I work for uses them all the time. They've set us up a web page, with a template to base new pages 
from. As well, they've given us accounts to log in, and manage web parts.

My web development experience has always involved IDEs and source code. With SharePoint I feel very limited developing / designing within the web browser WYSIWYG system.

Are there other tools MS provides that allow you a different view to manage the contents of a SharePoint page?

Comment: What sharepoint? 2013 hopefully?

Comment: 2008 is what I'm being told, though I have no access to the server it's on.

Comment: It's pretty much WYSIWYG, unless you want to use some html, you could try out [sharepoint designer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SharePoint_Designer). Learning sharepoint will probably prove useful, 2013 is more powerful